# How to get 'n' random points between start and end coordinates in python?

Tags: python, random, coordinates, uniform-distribution

I have a starting coordinate (x1,y1) and an ending coordinate (x2, y2). I want to generate 'n' random points between start and end coordinates without any duplicates. How to do this with python?

I know that a simple way would be to generate 'n' x values and 'n' y values. So we get n*n pairs and I choose 'n' among them with no duplicates. This way I mayn't get a uniform distribution of random points. Any other way to do this?

Edit: I require floating point coordinates in the rectangle formed by the start and end coordinates as opposite corners.

Comment: This isn't clear. Are you trying to get floating point numbers or integers? What do you mean by "between"? Do you mean the line segment connecting the points (which is the mathematical definition of "between" in 2-dimensional space) or are you trying to get points on the rectangle which has those 2 points as opposite corners?

Comment: Generating random points in a rectangle is easy. But what do you mean by "So we get n*n pairs and I choose 'n' among them with no duplicates?"

Comment: If you are sampling floating point numbers, then the chance of getting the same point twice is vanishingly small. Why worry about it?

Comment: @BrianMcCutchon I mean if I generate 'n' x values and 'n' y values , then we have n<sup>2</sup> combinations and I can choose any 'n' among them. I just mentioned one of the naive approaches.

Comment: @JohnColeman the use of the phrase 'uniform random' suggests OP is asking about a uniform random variable, which is a variable that can assume any value over a continous interval with equal probability. Of course, due to the nature of `float` variables and their implementation, this is next to impossible in most programming languages, but I suppose whatever the library implementation offers for random floats is going to be considered uniform enough... The suggested mechanism  suggest a rectangle area - although I agree that '2^n' confuses things, as it only makes sense for int on that interval

Comment: @JohnColeman yes you're right if precision is high,  but if the range of 'x' and 'y' overlap and precision is low then we might have duplicates

Comment: @hamsa if precision is low, you don't have a 'uniform random' distribution though, so what's the point?

Comment: If you allow for some discretisation (going against the 'uniform random'), you could simply generate random pairs and check against previously generated pairs to exclude duplicates - the odds of that algorithm not stopping are vanishingly small and the implementation is more straightforward than picking and removing random pairs from a collection of all possibilities

Comment: @Grismar yes you may be right. I cannot ensure that a uniform random variable is always generated but can assume so while generating random numbers because if precision is high then possibility of duplicates is very very small. I am editing the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TL;DR:

```
from random import uniform


def gen_coords(x1, y1, x2, y2, n):
    result = set()
    # loops for each addition, avoiding duplicates
    while len(result) < n:
        result.add((uniform(x1, x2), uniform(y1, y2)))
    return result
```

Arguably, practically:

```
from random import uniform


def gen_coords(x1, y1, x2, y2, n):
    return [(uniform(x1, x2), uniform(y1, y2)) for _ in range(n)]
```

Considering that the odds of collisions are tiny.

Assuming that "between start and end coordinates" means in a rectangular section between these two corners in a Cartesian coordinate system (i.e. flat, 2D).

And assuming that a "uniform distribution" is achieved sufficiently ignoring the non-uniform distribution of floating point values. (i.e. not the exact same number of floating point values on any interval of equal length, nor a constant distance between floating point values in a continuum)

There's basically three ways of ensuring the randomly generated points are not duplicated:

1. pick them from a collection of possible values, removing each pick to avoid picking it again;
2. generate values within the allowed space, checking each pick against previous picks to avoid adding duplicates (and re-picking values until a new one is generated);
3. generate values and add to the set until the desired set size, removing duplicates after generation if any and repeating the process until done.

The first option can be a good choice if the space from which values are picked is of similar size to the target set size. However, when picking points with random floating point coordinates in some space, this is unlikely.

The second choice is the most straightforward, but can be expensive to compute if the target set size is large, as every new pick causes more comparisons.

The third choice is a bit more involved, but avoids comparisons until a candidate target set has been completed and certainly the best choice if the odds of collisions are small.

As a variant of the second choice, you could pick a target data structure that simply avoids the addition of duplicates altogether, relying on the language / interpreter to perform the checking more efficiently than any algorithm written in the language would be able to.

In Python, this means using a `set` instead of a `list`, which is the fastest way to achieve the result and would likely be the way you'd check for duplicates in the third option anyway - so you may as well use it right away and go with the variant of the second option.

Note that both the 2nd and 3rd option have a major flaw in case you're trying to create a set in the range of the selection function that's larger than the domain of the selection function. But for the given problem that's unlikely except for extremely large 'n'.

A solution (pitting the second option against the third):

```
from random import uniform
from timeit import timeit


def pick_coords_restricted(x1, y1, x2, y2, n):
    result = set()
    # loops for each addition, avoiding duplicates
    while len(result) < n:
        result.add((uniform(x1, x2), uniform(y1, y2)))
    return result


def pick_coords_checked(x1, y1, x2, y2, n):
    result = []
    # loops once for attempt, checking after each iteration
    while len(set(result)) < n:
        if len(result) > 0:
            result = list(set(result))
            result += [(uniform(x1, x2), uniform(y1, y2)) for _ in range(n - len(result))]
        else:
            result = [(uniform(x1, x2), uniform(y1, y2)) for _ in range(n)]
    return result


print(timeit(lambda: pick_coords_restricted(0, 0, 1, 1, 1000), number=10000))
print(timeit(lambda: pick_coords_checked(0, 0, 1, 1, 1000), number=10000))
```

Result (on my hardware):

```
4.3799341
3.9363368000000003
```

I get consistently, but marginally better results for the `pick_coords_checked` function - I would favour the clarity of the first implementation.

Comment: FYI: out of curiosity, I tried running `pick_coords_checked` a few dozen times with `n = 1000000000` (a billion) and it never led to a second iteration. As indicated in the comments, the odds of a duplicate are vanishingly small.